# Trigger mouseevents with fast mouse movements completely

Tags: javascript, performance, mouseevent

The browser checks the mouse position from time to time. And if it notices changes then triggers the events.

That means that if the visitor is moving the mouse very fast then some DOM-elements may be skipped!

That’s good for performance, because there may be many intermediate elements. We don’t really want to process in and out of each one.

On the other hand, we should keep in mind that the mouse pointer doesn’t “visit” all elements along the way. It can “jump”!!!

In some cases it could be useful to capture all elements by mouseover, mouseenter or mouseleave no matter how fast the mouse is moving, so is there a possibility to do something with javascript to handle it?

[image]

Comment: I think in most cases the cursor does actually jump the distance on an OS level and isn't actually picked up in the intermediate locations by the browser. My first thought would be, depending on your application, to draw a straight line between mouseover locations that you do pick up and check if it intersects with any elements in between.

Comment: a wild rating bar appeared on my mind upon checking the attached image - if it's the case, you should treat it as "string" you attach and stretch from the that point anywhere the mouse go